# Memcache Viewer crashes dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

When I click on Memcache Viewer the whole dashboard crashes and I have to login again.  This is really worrying me as we are serving data to many users.

> A server error has occurred.

Is there a way to see the internal logs?

I can't see anything in `logs` nor `admin logs`.

Is there any other way to reset the Memcache?

[image]